# ¿Como puedo recorrer una tabla html como si fuese una tabla de coordenadas?

Tags: php, jquery, html, algoritmos

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando insertar en base de datos unos valores que coloco en una tabla  (dinámica)  html con campos editables, ya tengo la función que inserta, pero mi problema es como relacionar el valor que coloco en la tabla con lo que deseo a través de un jquery.

Así construyo mi tabla:

```
 if (isset($dataRubroTerm)) {

// el script declarado en esta parte del controlador justo antes de la tabla hace que funcionen los eventos jquery
            $html = "

<script>

$('.prueba').on('focusin','tr',function(){
    $( '.prueba td ' ).focusout(function( event ) {
      var precio= $(this).text();

      console.log(+precio);return false;

    });
});

</script>

<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover prueba'> 
                    <tr>
                       <td> <b>Rubro seleccionado - " . $dataRubro->descripcion /*aca cambia dependiendo de el rubro que se seleccione*/. "</b>  </td>  
                       <td> <b>PRECIO MAR</b>  </td>  
                       <td> <b>PRECIO ANA</b>  </td>  
                       <td> <b>PRECIO DE CAJA</b>  </td>  
                       <td> <b>PRECIO EXT</b>  </td>  
                       <td> <b>MARCAS</b>  </td>  
                    </tr>  ";


            foreach ($dataRubroTerm AS $fila[0]) { // aca se autogenera la tabla.  


                $PrecioMar = Monitoreo::buscarPrecios($idMonitor, 1, $fila[0]->id_rub_term); //Esto hace la busqueda por bdd a ver si hay precios guardados previamente , al igual con la marca.
                $PrecioAna = Monitoreo::buscarPrecios($idMonitor, 2, $fila[0]->id_rub_term);
                $PrecioDCaja = Monitoreo::buscarPrecios($idMonitor, 3, $fila[0]->id_rub_term);
                $PrecioExt = Monitoreo::buscarPrecios($idMonitor, 4, $fila[0]->id_rub_term);
                $marcas = Monitoreo::buscarPrecios($idMonitor, 5, $fila[0]->id_rub_term);
                $html .= "<tr>
                        <td> " . $fila[0]->fkPresentacion->descripcion . " </td>";
                $html .= "<td class='numeric prueba' contenteditable='true'> " . ($PrecioMar == "" ? '0.00' : $PrecioMar) /*se coloca un condicional if (?) para usar la busqueda por base de datos y ver si hay o no hay algo guardado previamente*/ . "</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='numeric prueba'  contenteditable='true'>" . ($PrecioAna == "" ? '0.00' : $PrecioAna) . " </td>";
                $html .= "<td class='numeric prueba' contenteditable='true'>" . ($PrecioDCaja == "" ? '0.00' : $PrecioDCaja) . "</td>";
                $html .= "<td class='numeric prueba'  contenteditable='true'>" . ($PrecioExt == "" ? '0.00' : $PrecioExt) . "</td>";
                $html .="<td>" . ($marcas == "" ? 'Sin marca' : $marcas) . "</td></tr>";


            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola puedes ser mas claro con lo que quieres lograr? Edita tu pregunta y explica mejor que quieres lograr, cuales son los errores y el codigo que haz intentado implementar

Answer (score 1):

Contesto a tú pregunta acerca de cómo recorrer una tabla, entiendo que lo quieres hacer con JavaScript:

```js
function foreach(root, selector, callback) {
   if (typeof selector == 'string') {
      var all = root.querySelectorAll(selector);
      for (var each = 0; each < all.length; each++) {
         callback(all[each]);
      }
   } else {
      for (var each = 0; each < selector.length; each++) {
         foreach(root, selector[each], callback);
      }
   }
}

function walk(table) {
   var table = document.getElementById(table);
   var data = [];
   if (table) {
      foreach(table, 'tr:not(:first-child)', function(row) {
         var record = [];
         foreach(row, 'td', function(cell) {
            record.push(cell.innerText);
         });
         data.push(record);
      });
   }
   /* data contiene los datos de la tabla */
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 3));
   return data;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1,1</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>1,3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
      <td>2,3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
      <td>2,3</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="walk('table')">Recorrer</button>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente puede ser más fácil:

```js
function getcoordValue(){
  var coords = document.getElementById('coordsInput').value.split(',');
  var x = parseInt(coords[0]) - 1;
  var y = parseInt(coords[1]) - 1;
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[y].getElementsByTagName('td')[x].innerText)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="coordsInput" placeholder="coords"/>
    <button onclick="getcoordValue()">get value</button>
</body>
</html>
```